# How to perform arithmetic operations from formula stored in another table in sql / pgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, finance

I am new to sql and trying to solve a very specific scenario.

I need to build financial statements like profit & loss, balance sheet, cashflow.

Consider these 2 following tables

1. financials

| id | company_id | dateEnd | field_id | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2010-01-01 | sales | 100 |
| 2 | 101 | 2011-01-01 | sales | 110 |
| 3 | 101 | 2012-01-01 | sales | 120 |
| 4 | 101 | 2010-01-01 | sales_cost | 50 |
| 5 | 101 | 2011-01-01 | sales_cost | 60 |
| 6 | 101 | 2012-01-01 | sales_cost | 70 |

2.  statement_sequences

| id | statement_id | sequence | label | formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Revenue | sales |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Expenditure | sales_cost |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | Operating Profit | sales - sales_cost |

My question here is, How can I define relationship between these two tables and how to get following output ?  I need to evaluate formula stored in statement_sequences table against financials table and need results as below

3. Required Output results

| compnay_id | statement_id | sequence | label | 2010-01-01 | 2011-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 1 | Revenue | 100 | 110 | 120 |
| 101 | 1 | 2 | Expenditure | 50 | 60 | 70 |
| 101 | 1 | 3 | Operating Profit | 50 | 50 | 50 |

Please note following points.

- This is a very short set of rows. I have many distinct fields other than sales and sales_cost so storing them in column might not be feasible.
- It is okay if query performance is not that good as I will be storing the output results in a materialized view.
- I am currently using postgresql but open to switch to another db if required for compatibility.

  Any suggestion / help is appreciated.

I believe combining a custom sql function that evaluates formula against rows of financials table, and crosstab function might work but now sure how.

Comment: You'll learn faster and more thoroughly if you try doing the assignment yourself and ask for help on specific areas on which you find yourself stuck.

Comment: You can find lot of usefull answers searching for "PostgreSQL evaluate formula". Most close seems to be [Store a formula in a table and use the formula in a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33894/87400), which I guess also address the security issues using parameters.